# Problem importing opencv in shinylive inside quarto document

Tags: quarto, pyodide, py-shiny

I am trying to import a package supported by pyodide in shinylive under a quarto document. The main reason is I want to load an image using opencv. Firstly, this code:

````
```{shinylive-python}
#| standalone: true
#| viewerHeight: 420
from shiny import App, render, ui
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

```
````

give me the following error:

> Error starting app! Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "", line 202, in _start_app   File
> "/lib/python3.10/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1053, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 1030, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 1009, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 688, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 883, in
> exec_module   File "", line 241, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "/home/pyodide/app_4mr6ploxwzzzk07rc0d4/app.py", line 2, in 
> import cv2 ModuleNotFoundError: The module 'opencv-python' is included in the Pyodide distribution, but it is not installed. You can
> install it by calling:   await micropip.install("opencv-python") in
> Python, or   await pyodide.loadPackage("opencv-python") in JavaScript
> See https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/loading-packages.html for more
> details.

I also tried:

````
```{shinylive-python}
#| standalone: true
#| viewerHeight: 420
from shiny import App, render, ui
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyodide_js
await pyodide_js.loadPackage('opencv-python')
import cv2
```
````

But this gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 202, in
> _start_app   File "/lib/python3.10/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1053, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 1030, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 1009, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 688, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 879, in
> exec_module   File "", line
> 1017, in get_code   File "",
> line 947, in source_to_code   File "",
> line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed   File
> "/home/pyodide/app_4mr6ploxwzzzk07rc0d4/app.py", line 3
> await pyodide_js.loadPackage('opencv-python')
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

Comment: Any resolution to this issue? I'm getting a similar error with `shinylive`, but its for `shiny` oddly enough.